# IndexOutOfRange exception, while using a function from an unmanaged c++ dll

Tags: c#, dll, indexoutofrangeexception

I simply imported an unmanaged c++ dll in c#

```
[DllImport("OPT.DLL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "?optimise@@YAHPAH0000000PAN10011011100001110100001111HHPAD@Z", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
```

the function looks like this:

```
Public static extern unsafe int optimise(int* m, int* n, int* nb, int* ne,
          int* nncon, int* nnobj, int* nnjac,
          int* iobj, double* objadd,
          double* a, int* ha, int* ka, double* bl, double* bu,
          int* hs, double* xn, double* pi, double* rc,
          int* inform, int* mincor, int* ns, int* ninf, double* sinf, double* obj,
          double* z, int* nwcore, double* q, int* nq,
          int* komp, int* qsorte, int* sorte, double* vecSorte, double* vecKomp, double* matrixFrac, double* c, int lss, int lsk, byte* OkFile);
```

My Problem is that when i use this function it throws an IndexOutOfRange exception. How can this be? I dont use any Array or similiar whith this function.
I use it in a usual way:

```
int h    
h = optimise(...);
```

Thank you for helping!

Comment: How do you "use" it, could you show us in your question?

Comment: Wow, that's some function prototype!!

Comment: well i use it as i wrote. i just give all the pointers and variables a value and thats it. or what do u mean with how i use it?

Comment: IndexOutOfRangeException is a *managed* exception, C code cannot possibly generate it.  So you are looking in the wrong corner for this problem.  The [DllImport] attribute isn't visible, it needs to use CallingConvention.Cdecl.  The odds that you can successfully pinvoke this monster ought to be quite low.